# IE8 Out of memory using jQuery Validate submitHandler callback

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MessageAddForm').validate({
        rules: {
            'data[Message][message]': {
               ...
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'data[Message][message]': {
                 ...
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('input.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(form).submit();
        }
    });
```

In Firefox and Chrome works, in Internet Explorer 8 also works, but gives an "Out of memory at line: 3" error. The same error with this minimal code:

```
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).submit();
        }
```

The only way to avoid this error is to erase the submit handler, leaving only messages and rules. jQuery version is 1.7.1 and jQuery validation plugin is 1.9.0 I already have tested using different versions of jQuery: 1.5.2 and 1.6.1 The ones the author says to have tested:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I also tried an older version of the validation plugin but the Out of Memory error persists.

Versions affected are 32 and 64 bits. I don't know about older versions because I only give support to version 8 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the default form submit. Like so

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

Using $(form).submit(); re-triggers the validation function. The above code is used in the documentation link you provided.